# Actual CPU Core Temperature for AMD Threadripper 2970WX

Tags: cpu, temperature, amd-ryzen, sensors, lm-sensors

When we get the CPU temperatures for an AMD Threadripper 2970WX in Ubuntu 20.04, does the reported temperatures account for the 27 degree celcius offset?

Snippet of a `sensors` output:

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +69.0°C  
Tdie:         +42.0°C  
Tccd1:        +69.0°C  
Tccd2:        +67.5°C  
Tccd3:        +67.5°C
```

In this example, is `Tctl1` actually `69.0°C`, or do we have to subtract `27°C` ourselves to get the actual temperature of `42.0°C`